# Pagination, H1 and H2 and SEO

Tags: seo, pagination, h1

While completing a site in Drupal 7, I have been told by the SEO guy that I must use different H1 and H2 for every single page, including pagination. I have lists of quite a few pages, so I was thinking that I would need some solution of the type:

```
 <h1>Here some text describing the listing - Page 1 of 5</h1>
 <h2>Here some more subtext - Pag. 1/5</h2>
```

I don't know if this step is necessary, as I don't know how to dinamically solve the problem, as the H1 and H2 main texts will come from database and the only variable thing for one and other page would be the number.

Wouldn't it just suffice with the text without the - Page i of j parts?

Comment: It is definitely more recommendable to have _some text describing the listing_ rather than _Page i of j_ as the content for your `<h1>`. This in general, so why not here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The more unique the tags are from page to page, the better. Making it unique only by changing a digit might not be good enough.

If you can't make the tags more unique than just digits, you can consider using the word version of each number. For example, instead of:

```
<h1>Something - Page 1</h1>
<h1>Something - Page 2</h1>
<h1>Something - Page 3</h1>
```

You can do:

```
<h1>First page of Something</h1>
<h1>Second page of Something</h1>
<h1>Third page of Something</h1>
```

or even:

```
<h1>Something page one</h1>
<h1>Something page two</h1>
<h1>Something page three</h1>
```

or mix them up more:

```
<h1>Something the beginning</h1>
<h1>The second page of something</h1>
<h1>Something page three</h1>
```

In each group of tags, the first one in a group applies to the first page, the second to the second page, and third one to the last page.

If you can't make both headers unique between pages, at least make the content in H1 unique because H1 is more important than H2.